# How to delete the incoming Sms using BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing the application which can manage a device using SMS commands; the application must execute commands from SMS and delete this Sms. So, the code for managing works, but I can't delete the SMS. I have following BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final Uri SMS_INBOX_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String body = "";
        String number = "";

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                body += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                number +=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            }
        }

        SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String key=prefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.acc_key_key), "");

        if (body.trim().equals("#"+key)) {
            sendGPSCoordinates(context, number);
        } else if (body.trim().equals("?"+key)){
            sendResponces(context);
        }
        deleteSms(body, number, context);
    }

    private void deleteSms(String body, String number, Context context) {

        ContentResolver resolver=context.getContentResolver();
        int count=resolver.delete(SMS_INBOX_URI, "body = ? AND address = ?", new String[]{body, number});
        Log.e("count", String.valueOf(count));
/*      Cursor results=resolver.query(SMS_INBOX_URI, null, null, null, null);
        for (String str:results.getColumnNames()) {
            Log.e("column", str);
        }
}
```

and I have AndroidManifest.xml with needed permissions. The application receives the SMS, gets the SMS data from an Intent, manage the phone and tries to delete this SMS, but it always returns count is equals 0. I have tried to change URI for sms/inbox, but it doesn't works. Please, tell me, how can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Hello.what you want?delete new incoming message ? this is not your correct way to delete message.instand of number and body use Id to delete message.

Comment: Hey dude! Were you able to delete the SMS or STOP to receive in the naive app? I need help regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that you know, that an SMS-Message is send as ordered-Broadcast. So your Reciever has the ability to get them BEFORE the native SMS-app will get it (just set a higher priority inside Manifest than the native one). Therefore it should work to just `cancel` the Broadcast being send, that the SMS never reaches the native sms-app.

You could try it like this:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final Uri SMS_INBOX_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String body = "";
    String number = "";

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    if (bundle != null) {
        // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            body += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            number +=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        }
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String key=prefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.acc_key_key), "");

    if (body.trim().equals("#"+key)) {
        sendGPSCoordinates(context, number);
    } else if (body.trim().equals("?"+key)){
        sendResponces(context);
    }
    abortBroadcast();
}
```

Comment: thank you for response. but how can I delete the message? You told me that I need to abort the broadcast, but what do you think about deleting?

Comment: I thought, that if you abort the Broadcast in a way that the native SMS-app never receives it, it also has no chance to save it, and therefore no deletion is necessary

Comment: please note: in the implementation above EVERY SMS will be deleted your BroadcastReciever recieves. only abort the Broadcast if you are shure, that it was 'your' SMS, because else NO SMS is being delivered

Comment: @RafaelT - Bro what is the `R.string.acc_key_key` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public final void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
         Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            String messages = "";


            if ( extras != null )
            {
                // Get received SMS array
                Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( SMS_EXTRA_NAME );

                // Get ContentResolver object for pushing encrypted SMS to the incoming folder
               // ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

                for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i )
                {
                    SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

                    String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
                    String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
                    long date = sms.getTimestampMillis();
```

}

after this write query to get last message

and then fire your delete method .

its working good to delete last incoming message .

Hop you can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you...

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

```
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String number="";
    String Message="";      
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];         
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);             
            number = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();  
            Message = Message + msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("number:::", number);            
        PubVar.IN_SMS++;
        Savesms( number,Message,PubVar.PHONENO, context);
        long counted=deleteSMS(context);
        //long count=counted++;
        //PubVar.DELETED_SMS=counted;
        System.out.println("Deleted sms :"+ counted);
    }

}

//message deletion
private int deleteSMS(Context context)
{
    Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    int count = 0;
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(deleteUri, null, null,null, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) 
    {
        try
        {
            // Delete the SMS

            String pid = c.getString(0); // Get id;
            String uri = "content://sms/" + pid;
            count = context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);
            PubVar.DELETED_SMS=PubVar.DELETED_SMS+count;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("error in deleting " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    c.close();

    return count;

}
```